# view friends email with fb api, or send them a email with invite

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

is it possible and how? i try fb graph, api, javascript sdk , and dont know how to see friends emails, only name and id is available

twoo.com and netlog.com CAN see my friends emails and send them invite directly to email, from *@twoomail.com

Answer (score 0):

have you asked for the email permission from your users?
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/

this permission is not granted to your app by default.
once you ask for it, and users grant it, you can access it via the graph api

as for inviting users, you can also use the request dialog:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

Answer (score 0):

"Note: There is no way for apps to obtain email addresses for a user's friends."

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/email-permissions/

Its not allowed

Comment: And I am sooo glad that is the case :)